# Replacing android Fragment from Main activity

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and am completely stuck. I keep getting an exception when I try to inflate my Fragment.

Here's my project details:
 This is a TabHost project. I have a "dummy" activity for each tab. Each tab "dummy" activity has a linear layout that I use to inflate the group of Fragments for that tab to. When I create the activity under a given tab from my main activity, I add a default Fragment for that activity. Everything works perfect.

Now for my issue:
 I have an ActionBar Menu that is dynamically built depending on which tab is focused. When the user clicks a menu item, I need to replace the current Fragment on the focused tab activity. Because the ActionBar is on Main Activity and not the host activity for the focused Fragment, I am having trouble inflating the Fragment from the Main Activity. I've spent a few full days now trying to figure out how to do this. No matter what I do, I get "No view found for id 0XXXXXXX Fragment.". I'm assuming this is because the Main Activity is not tied to the FragmentManager of the tab activity that is used to host the Fragments.

Any suggestions on how I can replace the fragment on the host activity from the Main Activity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the use of FragmentActivity at http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/